# Facebook FQL: get UIDs who likes a url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to use the graph api or the javascipt SDK.

I've tried

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?access_token=<ACCESTOKEN>&query=SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id="http://www.google.se"
```

but i didnt get any results. I don't know how to do this using the javascript SDK.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the user id of people who like your page.  If you have an authenticated user, that like table can be used to get the pages that the current user or their friends like, but you can see all likes across Facebook for a specific page.